# Is there a way to connect to a Cloud SQL instance using psql and run a command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, psql, google-cloud-sql

The psql utility used to access a Cloud SQL instance seems to work differently from the original PostgreSQL psql client.

I'm not sure, but it seems that it is only possible to use psql to connect to the instance.  I was not able to find all the psql parameters available for Cloud SQL, so I'm wondering if it is possible to run in the CLI something like:

psql "sslmode=disable dbname=postgres user=postgres hostaddr=[INSTANCE_IP] command=[COMMAND]".

This would help me run some scripts automatically. Can someone confirm if this is somehow possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could connect either [using SSL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl) or [without encryption](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#connect)

Comment: Yes, I can connect using psql, but I was not able to connect and run a command with the -c parameter, so I would like to know if it is possible to do that with Cloud SQL.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your inquiry, yes, you can by doing it this way `psql "sslmode=disable dbname=postgres user=postgres hostaddr=[INSTANCE_IP]" -c '\x' -c 'SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;'`

Comment: I tried the way you showed, but psql ignores the arguments after the quotes, then I tried to remove the conninfo string and I was able to connect it. The sslmode parameter cannot be specified this way, but it think it tries to use SSL certificates regardless. I'm not sure about the security implications of that.

Comment: The steps that I did was: Created a new PostgreSQL instance, set the [authorization](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip#configure-instance-mysql) to 0.0.0.0/0 for testing purposes, executed the aforementioned command, I got the information from the query with no issues. Tried from the Google Cloud Shell too successfully.